# Count unique users if user visit n times

Tags: algorithm, redis, bloom-filter

I want to implement FreqCapping in an ad network. I want to serve a campaign to unique users only n time in day. If n=1, I could implement this with BloomFilter in redis, but usually n is greater than 1. Is there any data structure (even probabilistic data structure) that aims this issue? And is that implemented in redis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing the [Count-min sketch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count%E2%80%93min_sketch), and while Redis core doesn't have it, [RedisBloom](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisbloom/CountMinSketch_Commands/) does :)

Answer (score 1):

If `n` is small, just use a bloom filter on `'1x' + user`, `'2x' + user`, ..., `n + 'x' + 'user'`.  As a detail, check them in random order.  This means that when the user has been seen only a small portion of the time, you will have fewer lookups.

If `n` is large, consider only doing a fixed number of random lookups.  That trades performance when you're close to your limit with sometimes choosing not to fill when you're close to your limit.  For example with a maximum of 4 lookups, at 50% of your way to the limit you make the right choice over 90% of the time, and at 80% of the way to the limit you still make the right choice around 60% of the time.  And if `n=20`, you're saving a *lot* of time when you've hit the limit.

I am sure that there is some kind of special bloom filter that achieves similar limits where you check/set a random subset of the hash functions every time (checking more than you would set).  But you won't find that special structure already pre-built in Redis.

---

The probabilistic version that I am suggesting is this:

```
def is_available(user, k=4, n=20):
    tried = []
    for 1..k:
        i = rand(n)
        while i in tried:
            i = rand(n)
        id = user + ":" + str(i)
        if bloomfilter.lookup(id):
            tried.append(i)
        else:
            bloomfilter.add(id)
            return True
    return False
```

The point of randomization is to reduce how many lookups you need.  If you go in the same order each time, then on the 10th visit you'll have 9 lookups before you find that they are not over quota.  But if `n` is 20 and you are proceeding in random order, half the time the first lookup will be enough.  This reduces round trips, which improves performance, which matters a lot in adtech.

Comment: Great idea wrt using multipe bloom filters, but I've taken the liberty to offer another exotic data structure.

Comment: It's in interesting idea (sure, count-min sketch is an alternative, but possibly needs more memory). What I don't understand is "random order". How would it help? Could you describe the algorithm in more detail (with pseudo-code for lookup and add)?

Comment: @ThomasMueller I added code and a brief explanation.